# Why am only hearing noise or no sound?

Tags: speaker, tmrpcm

Alright, there is something missing in the question, **I was able to hear one sound of the files** and the others apply to the question I asked and that is why I am wondering. what is happening!

Here is the code:

```c
#include <SD.h>                      // need to include the SD library
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4  //using digital pin 4 on arduino nano 328, can use other pins
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...
#include <SPI.h>

TMRpcm tmrpcm;   // create an object for use in this sketch

void setup(){

  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9; //5,6,11 or 46 on Mega, 9 on Uno, Nano, etc

  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
    Serial.println("SD fail");  
    return;   // don't do anything more if not
  }
  tmrpcm.play("music.mp3"); //the sound file "music" will play each time the arduino powers up, or is reset
}

void loop(){  

  if(Serial.available()){    

    if(Serial.read() == 'p'){ //send the letter p over the serial monitor to start playback

      /* These are spkean Numbers */

     // tmrpcm.play("1-24bit.wav");
     // tmrpcm.play("1-16bit.wav");
     // tmrpcm.play("200-insane.mp3");   
     // tmrpcm.play("music.mp3")       // Strangely this is the working perfectly with good sound
     // tmrpcm.play("200-standard.mp3");
        tmrpcm.play("200.wav");        // from https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/index.jsp
    }
  }

}
```

Everything is good when I play this `tmrpcm.play("music.mp3");` but the others I hear aliens sounds expect this `tmrpcm.play("200.wav");` which I can hear the number two hundred but I feel the sound is 4-bit depth which very noisy. The files used in the code are [**here**](https://github.com/noajm/Audio-For-Arduino)

For clarification previously, I thought it was amplifying issues which then I had to used **LM386** but the sound was the same noise with `tmrpcm.play("200.wav");` and later when I tried this `tmrpcm.play("music.mp3");` I was shocked it worked perfectly like what I need it to be!  so I was curious I removed the **LM386** and played this `tmrpcm.play("music.mp3");` again and worked alright just maybe less volume.

Comment: Should I try to record a sound again with a lower pitch?

Comment: you renamed the sample file "music" to "music.mp3"? the library can play only prepared sound files https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki

Comment: Yes, that is correct and it was working. I made to `music.mp3` and  `music.wav` because I just was curious. I was going to rename `200.wav` to `200` but did not know how my Mac was not allowing me.

Comment: So how I do play spoken numbers from 1 to 100 as `prepared sound files`? Can I record them?

Comment: @Juraj I'm so dumb that link you sent has the solution... I will try it when I go home... sorry I just hate to read so that why I skip links. They are a smaller version of books.

Comment: @Juraj - Alright, I guess since that time I been trying to follow the author instructions but as always l have to struggle... So I tried to create `wav` same as the one working `https://imgur.com/a/TuMAYQa` but  I can not get close to that info as seen here `https://imgur.com/a/NjnggDd`

Comment: @Juraj I guess I will stick with this one `tmrpcm.play("200.wav");` and get over the noise I tried low pass filter but not working. I don't know!!

Comment: @Juraj - will you upload sample `.wav` has a spoken number and upload it to your `Github` because I'm frozen in this step and can not search further

Comment: This wonderful site `https://www.online-convert.com/` doing what I need, just need to store a file to SD and test the sound!

Comment: Oh yeah, I am hearing my sound there now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Juraj mentioned it was solved by changing the setting and I was able easily to play the sound when I matched the setting to this file:

[image]

So, I could not create one from scratch matches above setting but I was able to convert existing sound through this [site](https://www.online-convert.com/)
which allowed me to convert with desire setting and here finally the exiting sound has matched the setting:

[image]